# Pydoc won't run on command prompt

Tags: python, windows, pydoc

I'm working through this "Learn python the Hard Way" book and the book is now saying to run
'pydoc open'
I do this and get the response that pydoc is not an internal or external command etc. 
I've trying adding 'C:\Python27\lib\pydoc.py' to PATH and restarting my computer but it still hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Python is probably not in your path. you must add it in your path either by using the GUI or something like this:

```
set PATH = PATH;/path/to/pydoc/
```

This is a windows example, but it should not be hard to convert to a *nix version. The `export` command can be used in that case.